# Generating random background

Tags: python

I have a settings.blend where I have configured all of my various objects. Within the static.blend file, I want to replace 2 objects - a main character and an image background. I have 1000 glb files of the main character which I want to loop over to create a scene. In each scene I would also like to generate a random image background (of which I have 5 random image backgrounds).

The image background does not seem to be randomly generated and only a static background is picked for all 1000 loops. (I have followed this tutorial to try to randomise images (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OuMWVQALrgw&ab_channel=10MinuteArtist).

[![Image Node Configuration][1]][1]

```
#generate random background
        bpy.data.materials["Random"].node_tree.nodes["Group"].inputs[1].default_value = num1   


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kYW0.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import bpy, random

mats        = bpy.data.materials
imgs        = bpy.data.images
ran_imgs    = ["p1.png", "p2.png", "p3.png", "p4.png", "p5.png"]

mat         = mats["Material"]
nodes       = mat.node_tree.nodes
node        = nodes["Image Texture"]

n           = random.randint(0, 4)
node.image  = imgs[ran_imgs[n]]
```

It should work with correct setting

[image]

blend file:
https://www.mediafire.com/file/vdgolhvvxruu0li/ran.blend/file

Comment: Currently I am getting an error at "node.image  = imgs[ran_imgs[n]]" where the error is "AttributeError: 'ShaderNodeGroup' object has no attribute 'image'". Would you know how to fix it?

Comment: What is your node type? It only work on node where have attribute image.

Comment: Yes, I am using an image texture link. I have linked my image configuration above

Comment: use one image texture and check your node name

Comment: is it possible for you to send me your .blend file please

Comment: ok, the blend file is uploaded.

Comment: apologies, I think it is deleted. Could you reupload it again please

Comment: you can upload it to google drive too if possible! thank you so much

Comment: Thank you very much!